# Can we call OnLongClickListener inside CustomAdapter class?

Tags: java, android, onlongclicklistener

```
  TextView deleteBtn = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

  deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something

               SQLiteDatabase db = new DBhelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
               db.delete(DBhelper.TABLE1, DBhelper.C_ID + "=?", new String[] {Integer.toString(list.get(position).getId())});
               db.close();
               list.remove(position);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

This is my simple onclick listener in `CustomAdapter` class, I need to change this `Onclicklistener` as `OnLongClickListener` .How Can I do this?

Comment: No actually,it's giving me error(all codes comes with red lines),so I thougth we can't call OnLongClickListener in custom adapter class

Comment: setOnClickListener => setOnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener => View.OnLongClickListener, void onClick=>boolean onLongClick ... where is the problem? obviously changing method from void to boolean make some obvious consequences, but so obvious, that it is not even worth to mention about it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by red lines?

```
deleteBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //DO SOMETHING
        return false;
      }
    });
```

check that you are passing a `OnLongClickListener` instance instead of a `OnClickListener` to the method.

Comment: Okey ,actually I put void instead of boolean, I didn't thought  that, this was the mistake.now it's working.thank you for your answer.